# TcpClient not reading whenever new data is available

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I'm trying to create a program that listens to my server via a TCP Socket so it can be notified. For example, if I update the price of an item, all clients connected to the TCP Server gets sent a JSON string telling them so. The idea is that my C# program maintains this TCP Socket throughout run time, reading from the socket whenever there is new data.

My problem is that `TcpClient` is refusing to read past the first round of bytes being sent. It reads that and then just stops working altogether. Code is as follows:

```
TcpClient _client;
static int readBytesLength = 1024;
Byte[] readBytes = new byte[readBytesLength];

private void initClientConnection() {
    _client = new TcpClient();
    _client.BeginConnect(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT, new AsyncCallback(connectCallback), _client);
}

private void connectCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
    if (_client.Connected) {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
        this.beginReading();
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect, trying again!");
        this.initClientConnection();
    }
}


private void beginReading() {
    readBytes = new byte[readBytesLength];
    _client.GetStream().BeginRead(readBytes, 0, readBytesLength, receiveCallback, _client.GetStream());
}

private void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult result) {
    Console.WriteLine("Read Callback!");
    if (_client.GetStream().CanRead) {
        string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readBytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Stream got \n{0}", response);
    }
    this.beginReading();
}
```

Again, I only receive 1 batch data and it just stops receiving.

```
Stream got 
-----Received-----
{"status":"SUCCESS","message": "Log in confirmed (2)"}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that code works at all. Where are your calls to `EndConnect` and `EndRead`? You also don't have any kind of loop, so you are only telling the client to do one read. I think you need to study the `TcpClient` documentation a bit more to fully understand how the class works

Comment: My bad, I lifted (and modified) this off of the example on MSDN and assumed the loop of `beginReading()` -> `receiveCallback()` -> `beginReading()` -> ... would be enough. I also didn't want to run it through a `while (true)` loop as I needed it to be non blocking.

there was no mention of `EndConnect` and `EndRead`. May I know what article you are referencing with regards to this?

Comment: My bad, I missed the call to `beginReading` at the end of `receiveCallback`. Still, what examples did you use? `End<method>` is an integral partner of `Begin<method>`. For example, the [MSDN page for `BeginConnect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145193%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) mentions that you must call `EndConnect` in the Remarks section

Comment: I thought `EndConnect` is only called once I'm done with the connection? In which case I never call it in that I need the connection to persist throughout runtime.

Comment: No, you call `EndConnect` when you're done connecting (generally in the callback)

Comment: Okay, I updated my code to run `EndConnect()` on the connect callback as well as `EndRead()` on the `receiveCallback()` but it's still not working. Still reads only the first batch of bytes and nothing after that.

Comment: Are you certain your server is sending data correctly? How are you handling multiple clients? Could you show us some of the server's code too?

Comment: Because on the server side, one TcpClient can only handle one connection. So if another connection to the server is made and you only have one TcpClient on the server, the previous connection will be discarded.

Comment: Also, how will you know when you've got the whole JSON string? You should look into _length-prefixing_.

Answer (score 1):

There are still a few weird things going on in your code. There's no reason to use `Stream.CanRead` where you are using it, and you aren't using the correct overload of `Encoding.GetString`. I've cleaned up your example a bit and fixed some oddities/unnecessary bits.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class TcpConnection
{
    private const int BUF_SIZE = 1024;
    private readonly byte[] buffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
    private readonly TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

    public void Start(IPAddress ip, int port)
    {
        client.BeginConnect(ip, port, ConnectCallback, null);
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        client.EndConnect(result);
        Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
    }

    private void StartRead()
    {
        if(!client.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected, can't read.");
            return;
        }
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE, ReadCallback, stream);        
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = (NetworkStream)result.AsyncState;
        int bytesRead = stream.EndRead(result);
        Console.WriteLine("Read Callback!");
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Stream got \n{0}", response);
        }
        StartRead();
    }
}
```